# Optimized version of sieving for primes

Tags: prime-numbers, sieve-theory

I was reading a piece of code that was an optimized version of Eratosthenis sieve for primes but I don't understand the logic and can't find online the formalized definition of it.
Basically for input `n` to generate all primes up to and including `n`, it considers as the max number of iterations to the process:

```
int size = Math.floor(0.5 * (n - 3)) + 1
```

and iteratively goes for `i = 0; i < size; ++i` considering that if `i` is prime then `(i * 2) + 3` is also prime and then marking as not prime all j `for j = ((i * i)* 2) + 6 * i + 3; j < size; j +=(i * 2 + 3)`
Can someone explain what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a standard sieve, optimized slightly for space but not for speed. Instead of an array with an entry for each positive integer, it uses an array with only entries for the odd numbers from 3 onwards. So entry $i$ in the array (with $0$-based indexing) represents the integer $2i+3$.

Note that contrary to what you said, it does not matter whether or not the index $i$ is prime, it only matters whether the number it represents, $2i+3$, is prime.

Anyway, the algorithm removes multiples of all numbers up to $n$. That is to say, the corresponding index $i$ is such that $2i+3\le n$. This leads to the expression you ask about.

That is actually not an optimized bound. Every composite number $\le n$ will actually have a factor that is $\le\sqrt{n}$, so really they could have lowered that bound significantly.

Comment: Your answer really helps a lot, thank you. How is the `Math.floor(0.5 * (n - 3)) + 1` being determined? If the process is to ignore evens shouldn't it have been `n/2`? Also how is the `((i * i)* 2) + 6 * i + 3`derived?

Comment: They could indeed have used $n/2$, or as I suggested $\sqrt{n}$ as the upper limit for $2i+3$. Note however that this only holds for the $i$ loop, not the $j$ loop which has to go all the way to $2j+3\le n$. Suppose $p=2i+3$ is prime. All multiples of $p$ must be marked by the $j$-loop. The multiples $2p$ up to $(p-1)p$ have already been marked as composite earlier because they have smaller divisors, so the first multiple for the $j$-loop is $p^2$. So we need the starting value to be such that $2j+3=(2i+3)^2$, which gives $j=2i^2+6i+3$.

Comment: Ah I see! `the  loop which has to go all the way to 2+3≤.` why in the approach I posted `j` goes up to `size`? I mean if we go over the sqrt it is not a prime anyway

Comment: The outer loop, the $i$-loop, loops over the indices to find the primes $p=2i+3$ generated so far. The inner $j$-loop goes over the indices of all multiples of $p$ to mark them as non-prime. The only reason the outer loop can stop at the index representing $\sqrt{n}$ is because the inner loop starts from the index representing $p^2$ and goes up to the index representing $n$, which means that the inner loop does nothing if $p^2>n$.

Comment: How is the Math.floor(0.5 * (n - 3)) + 1` derived by this logic?

Comment: $2i+3\le n$ means $i \le \frac{n-3}{2}$. Since $i$ is an integer, we can round the right hand side down to a whole number. If you then change the $\le$ to a $<$ in the for loop you need to add 1.

Comment: I think you are a genius man! Thank you so much for explaining this to me! I highly appreciate it for what's it worth

Comment: `Every composite number ≤ will actually have a factor that is ≤√, so really they could have lowered that bound significantly.` If `n=15` then sqrt(15) = 3.87 but if we bounded there we would have missed 7 which is prime. I guess I didn't understand the statement?

Comment: At the end, the entry for 7 has not been marked as composite, so it is correctly considered prime. The only other multiple of 7 that lies below n is 14, and that is implicitly considered composite because it is even and therefore does not even have an entry in the array. Even in the unoptimised case with the full array, 14 would have been marked as composite when all multiples of the prime 2 were being eliminated. If you cross off all multiples of 2 and/or 3 that lie below 15, you will be left with 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 - all the primes in that range.

Comment: ` the entry for 7 has not been marked as composite,` the outer loop `i` stops at 3 (since sqrt(15)=3.87. The inner loop would stop at <=n if I understood. But then what is the size of the array in the approach you mentioned? Not sqrt(n)?

Comment: The array is of size $n$ (or size of about $n/2$ in the optimized version) because we want to determine all the primes up to $n$, and need to store a flag for each of those numbers up to $n$.
This whole array optimisation is a distraction. Most of your questions have been about things that relate to the normal sieve of Eratosthenes, so you should review that some more. Try it out on paper with n=100. Make a note of when there are no more numbers to be crossed out, and figure out why that is.

Comment: I thought that with the optimization the array size would go to sqrt(n). With size of (N) or (N/2) I understand it (I think but I'll review again). With size sqrt(n) I got confused how 7 would be indexed